# Magento emails dont work 1.9

Tags: magento, email, magento-1.9.1

Am a newbie to magento, website is completely ready & all functionalities are working, except email. No email is sent or received from magento.
Even waited for 48 hours still no hope.

Pls help.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJHog.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mumx5.png

Update:

community/ASchroder_SMTPPro: couldn't connect to host

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away' in /home/apttrend/public_html/alayaonshop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 Stack trace: #0 /home/apttrend/public_html/alayaonshop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /home/apttrend/public_html/alayaonshop/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2 /home/apttrend/public_html/alayaonshop/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3 /home/apttrend/public_html/alayaonshop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 /home/apttrend/public_html/alayaonshop/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `core_se...', Array) #5 /home/apttrend/public_html/alayaonshop/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT`core_se...', Array) #6 /home/apttrend/public_html/alayaonshop/lib/Zen in /home/apttrend/public_html/alayaonshop/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 235

Reporting this error when installing the extension

Comment: Can you create a test php page and add a simple mail call: mail('youremail@yourdomain.com', 'Testemail', 'Testemail'); If you don't receive it then there is an issue with mail configuration on the server. It could be that mail is set to be delivered locally on the server but your mailbox might be elsewhere. Your hosts can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

After 1.9.1 version, magento send e-mails periodically. So you need to configure cronjob to your server. Configure your server to access the cron.sh or cron.php of your magento installation